# Wordpress user registration database

Tags: wordpress, plugins, registration

I'm new to plugin development. For a plugin, I want to add custom user fields and add them into the user meta database and then use the fields later on in front end.

But I'm a bit stuck with getting it right.
Could someone explain how to do this?

Comment: Can you show us what you already have, and/or give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hello maarten, 

I got nothing yet, i googled everywhere, but cant find it.

What i'm trying to achieve is:

When I register a new account (Student account/Teacher account), i want it to push the data to the database so i can use it later on at the front end side. Or is this possible when just save it at the profile page?

Comment: I agree with @MaartenBicknese if you want to get help on StackOverflow you need to give us something to work with, what is called an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to show you with an example. Lets say I want to create a new filed as **Facebook URL** for each user. So below is the code

```
/**
 * Creating custom field for each user
 */
function prefix_add_area_field( $user ) {

    ?>
        <h3>User Facebook URL</h3>

        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="area_id">Facebook URL</label></th>
                <td><input type="text" name="facebook_url" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'facebook_url', true )); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'prefix_add_area_field' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'prefix_add_area_field' );

/**
 * Saving the user field from admin panel.
 */
function prefix_save_user_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;
    //save text field
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'facebook_url', $_POST['facebook_url'] );
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'prefix_save_user_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'prefix_save_user_fields' );
```

If you want to display the custom field value ie Facebook URL in frontend then you can use **get_usermeta( $user_id, 'facebook_url', true )** in your theme file.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the input!
it shows up on the profile but it isnt showing up at the user registration form.
any way to add this?

Comment: which plugin you are using.. there must be an hook from which you can extend/add a custom field

Comment: i'm using a fresh clean install of wordpress, with my own plugin activated, no others.